# Does it make sense to OpenGL instead of SDL blitting functions?

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl, hardware-acceleration

I'm writing a simple 2d game using SDL and I was wondering, what if I just apply a bitmap texture to rectangles with OpenGL and use them instead of sprites, eliminating any calls to `SDL_BlitSurface`? Will my application become faster as a result of OpenGL hardware acceleration?

P.S.: My application will be running in windowed mode (not fullscreen), if that's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general, that should be faster and more scalable (you can draw more sprites before you start getting a performance hit).